# How to speed up laptop ASUS K53E by software

Tags: laptop

i made a fresh new installation of Windows 7, installed avg tune-up.

any suggeston about speed up perfomance of it.

Comment: This is off topic here. If it's a new installation and is slow, then it's more likely your hardware isn't powerful enough for your needs

Answer (score 1):

First of all, more information on configuration would be a great way to start your question. Then describe where you expect performance increase, overall system speed, multitasking, choppy YouTube playback - try to be more specific.

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=optimise%20windows%207&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) will give you a few things to try.

However in my experience your problem is most likely old hard disk and it's poor performance and/or lack of RAM.